# Delete html Row and Delete Column button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to achieve like the pic below:

[image]

I don't seem to get the "delete selected column" right and also Delete selected row; instead  the are deleting all rows and all columns.

So far I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
//*********************************Start Add Row **********************************************************
function addRowToTable(){
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl_sales');     //html table
  var columnCount =  tbl.rows[0].cells.length;        //no. of columns in table 
  var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;                     //no. of rows in table 
  var row = tbl.insertRow(rowCount);                  //insert a row method
    
    // For Every Row Added a Checkbox on first cell--------------------------------------
  var cell_1 = row.insertCell(0);                     //Create a new cell
  var element_1 = document.createElement("input");    //create a new element
  element_1.type = "checkbox";                        //set element type
  element_1.setAttribute('id','newCheckbox');         //set id attribute
  cell_1.appendChild(element_1);                      //Append element to created cell
  
  // For Every Row Added add a Select box on Second cell------------------------------
  var cell_2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element_2 = document.createElement('select');
  element_2.name = 'SelDist' + rowCount;
  element_2.options[0] = new Option('John Doe', 'value0');
  element_2.options[1] = new Option('Dane Doe', 'value1');
  cell_2.appendChild(element_2);
  
  // For Every Row Added add a textbox on the rest of the cells starting with the 3rd,4th,5th...  coloumns going on...
  if(columnCount >= 2){  //Add cells for more than 2 columns
      for (var i=3; i<=columnCount; i++) {
              var newCel = row.insertCell(i-1); //create a new cell           
              var element_3 = document.createElement("input");            
              element_3.type = "text"; 
              element_3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute     
              newCel.appendChild(element_3);
              }
       }
}
//***************************** End Add Row ***************************************************************
// *****************************Start Add Column**********************************************************
function addColumn() { 
         var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById('tbl_sales').tBodies[0];
         var rowCount = tblBodyObj.rows.length;
        
        //for every Coloumn Added Add checkbox on first row ----------------------------------------------
        var newchkbxcell = tblBodyObj.rows[0].insertCell(-1);
        var element_4 = document.createElement("input");
        element_4.type = "checkbox";
        element_4.setAttribute('id','newCheckbox');
        newchkbxcell.appendChild(element_4); 
        
        //For Every Coloumn Added add Drop down list on second row-------------------------------------
        var newselectboxcell = tblBodyObj.rows[1].insertCell(-1);
        var element_5 = document.createElement('select');
        element_5.name = 'SelProd' + rowCount;
        element_5.options[0] = new Option('Product11', 'value0');
        element_5.options[1] = new Option('Product12', 'value1');
        element_5.options[2] = new Option('Product13', 'value2');
        element_5.options[3] = new Option('Product14', 'value3');
        element_5.options[4] = new Option('Product15', 'value4');
        element_5.options[5] = new Option('Product16', 'value5');
        newselectboxcell.appendChild(element_5);
        
        // For Every Coloumn Added add a textbox on the rest of the row cells starting with the 3rd,4th,5th......  
         for (var i=2; i< tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) { //Add cells in all rows starting with 3rd row
              var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1); //create new cell
              var element_6 = document.createElement("input");
              element_6.type = "text"
              element_6.setAttribute('id', 'Newinput');
              newCell.appendChild(element_6)
            }
}
//*****************************Start Delete Selected Rows **************************************************
function deleteSelectedRows() {    
        var tb = document.getElementById('tbl_sales');
        var NoOfrows = tb.rows.length;          
         for(var i=0; i< NoOfrows; i++) {               
            var row = tb.rows[i];             
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; //get check box object               
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) { //wheather check box is selected                   
   tb.deleteRow(i); //delete the selected row                    
   NoOfrows--; //decrease rowcount by 1                   
   i--;               
  }             
 }
}
//*****************************End Delete Selected Columns **************************************************
//*****************************Start Delete Selected Columns ************************************************
function deleteSelectedColoumns() 
{
    var tb = document.getElementById('tbl_sales');//html table
    var NoOfcolumns =  tb.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table 
        for (var clm=3; clm< NoOfcolumns; clm++)
        {
             var rw = tb.rows[0];
             var chkbox = rw.cells[clm].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                { 
                    //-----------------------------------------------------
                    var lastrow = document.getElementById('tbl_sales').rows;
                    for (var x=0; x< lastrow.length; x++)
                    {
                        lastrow[x].deleteCell(clm);
                        
                    }
                    //----------------------------------------- 
                    NoOfcolumns--;
                    clm--;  
                }else
                { 
                alert ("not selected");
                return;
                }
        }

}
//*****************************End Delete Selected Columns **************************************************
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Distributor Sales</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="30" border="1" id="tbl_sales">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Products</strong></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="adclmbutton" id="addclmnbutton" value="Add Product" onclick="addColumn()" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Distributors</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Sales Grid</strong></td>
    <td><select name="select3" id="select">
      <option>Product 1</option>
      <option>Product 2</option>
      <option selected="selected">Product 3</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="addrowbutton" id="adrwbutton" value="Add Distributor" onclick="addRowToTable();"/></td>
    <td><select name="select6" id="select6">
      <option selected="selected">Jhon Doe</option>
      <option>Jane Doe</option>
      <option>David</option>
      <option>Kelvin</option>
      </select></td>
    <td><label for="textfield"></label>
      <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" width="50px" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Remove Selected Distributor" onClick="deleteSelectedRows()"/>
  <input type="submit" name="button4" id="button4" value="Remove Selected Product" onClick="deleteSelectedColoumns()"/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try putting an alert('Test!') right next to the code actually doing the removing to ensure that it is even running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```js
lastrow[x].deleteCell(clm);
```

to

```js
tb.rows[x].deleteCell(clm);
```

and also remove the branch

```js
//} else { alert ("not selected"); return; }
```

,then it works well. [Tested it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cZxHu/)

Comment: Thanks a lot.i was trying to do this using a tutorial.am not very good at java script.i have understood better now.

Comment: Glad it helped. I also learned javascript about 3 years ago, the essential was to understand how the page is represented in DOM. And also using a library like jQuery makes the programming muuch simpler. Well good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your deleteSelectedColumns function will always return after passing a column which is not selected:

```
/*...*/
if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
{
  /*...*/
}else
  alert ("not selected");
  return;
}
```

If the first column is not selected, for instance, none of the others will be looked at.

You are also using submit buttons to trigger your functions. These will refresh the page when pressed (reseting it to its original state), giving the impression that all rows and columns have been deleted. Try using

```
<input type="button" />
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

if table is static, then you can use the below to delete first, last column:

```
var allRows = document.getElementById('destination').rows;
    for(var i=0; i< allRows.length; i++) {
        if (allRows[i].cells.length > 0) {
            allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);// logic to remove the last column
            allRows[i].deleteCell(0);// logic to remove the first column of the modified table.     
      } 
}
```